# Divi Theme Builder , Adding a header and footer to a Wordpress template page

Tags: php, wordpress, divi-theme

I have a client that wants to convert their previous site to a Divi builder site. The previous site (the one to be updated) had a custom template page that used PHP, HTML, Ajax and Javascript code. It was all coded on one page.

On the previous site the custom template page was something like this:

```
<?php
/**
*
* Template Name: MB Grid New
*
**/

get_header(); ?>

--All the code--

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I am new to using Divi and was wondering how to best convert this template on the Divi platform. Can I continue to use the php template file in the Divi child theme and add something like get_divi_header() ? Or do I have to use a Divi code module ? I noticed that the get_header() function does not grab the Divi header.  Thanks Julie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The major advantage of Divi is DIVI PAGE BUILDER. You can just keep the previous page template as reference and you can develop that page using DIVI page builder without writing much of code. You can design a complete website using drag and drop functionality. 
There is no need to create page template.  Using Divi Page Builder, you can easily design a page.